# how to create below mysql query in kohana query builder

Tags: kohana

How can i create below query in Kohana Db Builder

```
SELECT @i:=0;
UPDATE `table_name` 
SET `order` = @i:=@i+1 
where `column_name`= '3337'
```

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate queries!

```
$q1 = DB::query(NULL, "SELECT @i:=0");
$q2 = DB::update('table_name')
        ->set(array('order','=',DB::expr('@i:=@i+1')))
        ->where('column_name','=','3337');

$q1->execute();
$q2->execute();
```